# jQuery validate depending on checkbox status

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have three fields in a form which is using jQuery validate.js:

```
<input type="text" id="StartDate" name="StartDate"><br />
<input type="text" id="EndDate" name="EndDate"><br />
<label for="AllDate"><input type="checkbox" name="AllDate" id="AllDate">All Dates</label>
```

I need #StartDate to be required on submit UNLESS #AllDate is checked. If #AllDate is checked, #StartDate is NOT required

Failed attempt(s):

```
rules: {
        StartDate: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return (! $("input[type='checkbox']:checked"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have had no luck creating a custom validation rule either. I am looking for a better way, one that works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
return !$("#AllDate").is(':checked');
```

Comment: I was trying to type out the whole function.  Brevity FTW.

Comment: great, I came up with this required: "#AllDate:checked" but that obviously works exactly opposite of what I wanted. Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom one for you

```
if(($("#AllDate").is(':checked')) == true ){
    //Do what you want when all dates are checked

} elseif (($("#StartDate").val()) != "") {
    //Do what you want with StartDate

} else {
    //You have to enter a date

}
```

Typing on the fly, See if that helps you or gives you a basic idea